# React click event not work when child element is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my code,

```
export default myComponent = () => {
    const handleClick = (e) => {
        const parent = e.target.parentElement;

        if (parent.classList.contains('selected_category')) {
            parent.classList.remove('selected_category');
        } else {
            parent.classList.add('selected_category');
        }
    };

    return (
        <>
            <ul>
                <li className="">
                    <a onClick={handleClick}>
                        content<span class="text-gray-25 font-size-12 font-weight-normal">
                            121
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li className="">
                    <a onClick={handleClick}>
                        content<span class="text-gray-25 font-size-12 font-weight-normal">
                            121
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </>
    );
}
```

I wrote this code for when **I clicked  tag element the parent element of it gets the class 'selected_category'** if it doesn't already have. But the problem here is when I click children  **class then 'selected_category' class is added to parent**  tag. is there any solution to prevent it?

This is my code in [sand box](http://%3Ciframe%20src=%22https://codesandbox.io/embed/adoring-marco-pg0ui?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark%22%20%20%20%20%20%20style=%22width:100%25;%20height:500px;%20border:0;%20border-radius:%204px;%20overflow:hidden;%22%20%20%20%20%20%20title=%22adoring-marco-pg0ui%22%20%20%20%20%20%20allow=%22accelerometer;%20ambient-light-sensor;%20camera;%20encrypted-media;%20geolocation;%20gyroscope;%20hid;%20microphone;%20midi;%20payment;%20usb;%20vr;%20xr-spatial-tracking%22%20%20%20%20%20%20sandbox=%22allow-forms%20allow-modals%20allow-popups%20allow-presentation%20allow-same-origin%20allow-scripts%22%20%20%20%20%3E%3C/iframe%3E)

Comment: Your code does exactly what you wrote it out to do. You are telling it to add the class to the parent of the clicked element which is the anchor tag in this case. So, it goes to the parent and adds/removes the class. Where is the problem?

Comment: Please share you code throgh Code sandbox, then we can able to give exact solution for your problem. Code Sandbox you can create from here https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: Hi @Katheer Thanks I added the code to sandbox

Comment: Code Sand box is not working, I think you just emberd the complete Iframe as a URL

Comment: @vimuth the link is not working.

Comment: You might want to use `e.currentTarget` instead of `e.target`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget. `e.target` may refer to a descendent, while `e.currentTarget` ensures that it always refers to the element to which the event listener is bound it.

Comment: Also please confirm, is this your exact question ...
When you click tag elemet you have to add 'selected_category'  class to li element (if li element doesn't has selected_category class) if li element has selected_category class you have to remove the selected_category class.  Also when you click other tag element you have to remove existing selected_category calss from all li element and add  selected_category calss to target parent element . IS THIS QUESTION IS CORRENT?

Comment: @Terry Adding currentTarget worked nicely thanks so much.

Comment: @katheer I wanted to change the class of parent <li> when <a> is clicked.  when <span> clicked also <li> class should needed to change since it's inside <a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To further elaborate on my comment: the issue comes from the use of `e.target`, which can refer to the element where the event listener is bound to *OR* its descendant(s). In this case, your `<a>` tag has `<span>` as a child. When a click event bubbles up to your `<a>` tag that originated from the inner `<span>`, then `e.target` will refer to the latter: which is not what you want.

To ensure that you get the reference to the actual element which the event listener is bound to is all times, you need to use [`e.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget):

> The `currentTarget` read-only property of the `Event` interface identifies the current target for the event, as the event traverses the DOM. It always refers to the element to which the event handler has been attached, as opposed to `Event.target`, which identifies the element on which the event occurred and which may be its descendant.

Therefore your updated function should simply use `currentTarget` instead, i.e.:

```
const handleClick = (e) => {
    // NOTE: Use e.currentTarget here instead of e.target
    const parent = e.currentTarget.parentElement;

    if (parent.classList.contains('selected_category')) {
        parent.classList.remove('selected_category');
    } else {
        parent.classList.add('selected_category');
    }
};
```